# Using ThinkPad Pro Dock with dual screen configuration

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, vga, dvi

At my company we are using Lenovo laptop with a ThinkPad Pro Dock 90W. As specified in the [documentation](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/itemdetails/40A10090US/460/76C432D671BE45E6A425ED543A9591C2):

- 1x DisplayPort 1.2 (Exclusive use with DVI-D)
- 1x DVI-D (Exclusive use with DisplayPort)
- 1x VGA

Which means that for a dual screen setup (identical [DELL u2412Mb](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=sg&cs=sgdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&sku=230-12091) with 1920 / 1200) I need to connect one monitor to VGA (compulsary!) and one monitor to either DVI-D or DisplayPort. I am sure there is a low level hardware issue here, but this is irrelevant here.

My question is: I find the white color to be brighter on the monitor digitally connected (DVI-D) while white color is a little darker on the right side (monitor analog connected).

I did some extensive testing using also a DisplayPort to DVI adaptor. The monitor that has the brighter white is the one connected to DVI-D or the DisplayPort to DVI-P adaptor.

Is this an impression ? Should I do something with my DELL screen configuration ? Should I buy some kind of adaptors (DVI splitter?) ?

Comment: So you tried using VGA and DVI on the same monitor? to see the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something that reduces the difference: I used: `'Preset Modes: Text'` on both monitors. I now find the white color a little darker on both sides. If I move a white background window across both screen the difference is now invisible.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, where is this configuration? on the screen itself or OS? or driver?

Comment: It's on the monitors directly